# android: scrolling of Horizontal ScrollView looks jerky

Tags: android, scroll, horizontalscrollview

I have this warning due to which my scolling of Horizontal ScrollView looks jerky.
Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Can anyone guide how can i solve this issue??
note :- this problem occurs only in Nexus 7 device ..on others it works fine.